# Confusion in the graph of displacement v/s time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

> A ball is dropped at $t=0$ from a height $h$ as shown, it collides elastically with the floor and rebounds to the same height. Draw displacement v/s time graph for the ball's motion taking downwards direction as positive.

[image]

Here, let's focus on the displacement v/s time graph. Shouldn't the displacement be below the X-axis from B to C? Since the downward direction is positive and the point from which the ball is dropped is considered as the origin, then when the ball is dropped, its velocity increases( is positive) along with the displacement(is positive). Once the ball hits the floor, it bounces up with the same velocity(but negative) since it's an elastic collision. While it is moving up, the displacement(now negative going upwards) is decreasing and finally becomes zero at the point from which it was dropped.

Since the displacement is negative after it bounces, shouldn't it be below the X-axis of displacement v/s time graph? I do understand that the gradient of displacement v/s time graph should be negative for the portion B to C. My question is directed at the plotting of displacement in the graph, like for velocity v/s time graph, the velocity is plotted negative from B to C which obeys the sign convention we have taken but why is it not followed for displacement v/s time graph?

Hoping for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

No, the displacement is never negative. The displacement here is taken *relative to the initial height*. At every point between A and C, the ball is below its initial height. Since the positive axis points down, a downward displacement is positive.

Here is a diagram showing the displacement vectors (blue arrows) at different points in the motion. It should be clear that the displacement is always directed downward.
[image]

Comment: Yes, the downward displacement is positive(the question states to take the downward direction as positive). My confusion is regarding the upward displacement from B to C. According to the sign convention as stated by the question, the upward displacement should be negative as downward is positive.  So shouldn't the graph of B to C be below the time axis for displacement v/s time graph (similar to a 4th quadrant where time is positive always but displacement is negative)? Distance will always be positive since it's a scalar, but the displacement can be negative as it is a vector.

Comment: @user3.14 The displacement is still positive after the bounce. A synonym for "displacement" is "position." The motion of the ball does not determine its displacement, only how the displacement changes over time. Displacement would only be negative if the ball reached a height higher than the height from which it was dropped.

Comment: @MarkH Yes! I just had this same thought. Thank you for the explanation. Appreciate it!

Comment: @user3.14 I included a diagram to try to clarify, although it seems like your confusion has been cleared up in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Assume no air resistance and the acceleration of the ball is $g\,\hat d$ where $\hat d$ is a unit vector pointing down.
The relevant kinematic equation is $s=s_{\rm i} +v_{\rm i}t+\frac 12 gt^2$ where $s$ is the displacement at time $t$, $s_{\rm i}$ the initial displacement, $v_{\rm i}$ the initial velocity, and $t$ the time.

In vector form for the downward motion is $ s\hat d=s_{\rm i}\,\hat d+ v_{\rm i}t\,\hat d+\frac 12 gt^2\hat d.$

$t=0$, displacement is $0\,\hat d$
$t=1$, displacement is $g/2\,\hat d$
$t=2$, displacement is $2g\,\hat d$
$t=3$, displacement is $9g/2\,\hat d$
All these displacements are positive and downward.

Suppose at $t=3$, rebound occurs and the velocity of the ball is $3g\,(-\hat d)= -3g \,\hat d$.

The equation of motion for the upward motion is $s\hat d=\underbrace{9g/2\,\hat d}_{\Large s_{\rm i}\,\hat d}+(\underbrace{-3g(t-3)\hat d)}_{\Large v_{\rm i}t\,\hat d}+\underbrace{\frac 12g(t-3)^2\hat d}_{\Large\frac 12 gt^2\hat d}$

$t=3$, displacement is $9g/2\,\hat d$  (positive)
$t=4$, displacement is $2g\,\hat d$  (same as at $t=2$ and positive)
$t=5$, displacement is $g/2\,\hat d$  (same as at $t=1$ and positive)
$t=6$, displacement is $0\,\hat d$  (same as at $t=0$)